# .net core e-mail confirm process in api

Tags: asp.net-core, email, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core 5.0 api and it's works well when the user register itself. When i send an e-mail to user for confirm his account i'm also sending a validation link like `https://localhost:44341/api/Account/VerifyAccount?email=uservuejs@example.com&token=Q6O79W6HXTT07GCMV0DM68DPGYNZAGCYFQNKFJ8954JAVS3M` .

But when the user clicks that link, nothing happens. It's doesnt even hit the api controller. I know, the problem is this is not a post or get request. I just could not understand the point how i am gonna create a post request when the user hits that confirm link.

Thanks for any recommend, have a good day.

VerifyAccount method:

```
#region /*VerifyAccount*/
        // POST: /api/Account/VerifyAccount
        [HttpPost("VerifyAccount")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyAccount(string token, string email)
        {
            try
            {
                if (token != null && email != null)
                {
                    var user = await _unitOfWorkUser.RepositoryUser.GetUserByEmailFirstOrDefault(email);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        if (user.UserIsEmailConfirmed != true && user.UserToken == token)
                        {
                            user.UserIsEmailConfirmed = true;
                            user.UserToken = null;
                            await _unitOfWorkUser.RepositoryUser.UpdateAsync(user);
                            await _unitOfWorkUser.CompleteAsync();
                            return Ok(new CustomOk(true, "Your account has been successfully verified. You can login now.", "nullObject"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Ok(new CustomOk(false, "You have already verified your account.", "nullObject")); 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Ok(new CustomOk(false, "You dont have permission to use this action.", "nullObject"));

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(new CustomBadRequest(false, "You need to fill required fields.", "nullObject"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log log = new()
                {
                    LogDescription = "try-catch " + ex.Message,
                    LogType = "try-catch",
                    TableID = "api/Account/VerifyAccount",
                    TableName = "User",
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedUserId = 0,
                    CreatedUserType = "Back-end"
                };
                await _unitOfWorkLog.RepositoryLog.CreateAsync(log);
                await _unitOfWorkLog.CompleteAsync();
                return NotFound(new CustomInternalServerError(false, "try-catch " + ex.Message, "nullObject"));
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Can you share controller method for validation?

Comment: @OnurkanBakırcı i did now.

Comment: When you use ````[HttpGet("VerifyAccount")]````, same error occurs? Did you debug it?

Comment: `I know, the problem is this is not a post or get request.` why do you assume that? A link results in a GET, but you posted a POST action. One that seems to be using the "repository" **anti**pattern too. Does your controller have a GET action named `VerifyAccount` as well?

Comment: If your code uses Entity Framework you gain *nothing* by renaming DbContext to UnitOfWork and DbSet to Repository. You only make your code harder to read. For example, there's no reason to "update" a modified entity that was initially loaded by a DbContext. The DbContext already tracks that entity and knows whether it was modified or not. You only need to call `SaveChanges` to persist any changes. As for logging to the database - there are no objects in this case. You aren't dealing with object persistence at all, you're using logging. The DB sink code shouldn't leak into the code

Comment: The logging code should be removed and replaced by .NET Core's own logging. The ILogger interface can already handle multiple parameters *and* exception objects. `logger.LogWarning("The person {PersonId} could not be found.", personId);` for example logs the exception, *and* the personId parameters separately. The providers configured in Startup.cs can store the exception, message and parameters separately. If you use a structured provider like Serilog you can write logs to database tables *and* store the params in separate JSON columns

Comment: @OnurkanBakırcı it worked. it was a small mistake by me, thanks for warning it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i solved with onurkan help. thanks for those comments, i will read all of it.

Comment: That comment says "Change POST to GET". Because a link can only result in a GET request

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yea yea, i did it and it started to work. i realise the problem know which is a mistake by me. for log system, i have a different purpose to do that. i'm trying to save those logs to the db so i can specialize them in the admin panel. you can think like notification system or etc

Comment: I know, because I do the same. In the logging configuration though, using Serilog and its database sink among others. All you need is to use a logging provider that writes to the database. Right now you leaked the logging code all over your action. There's *nothing* domain related in that exception handler, there's no unit of work to commit, it's all logging code, far more complex than needed.

Comment: I use Serilog to log to files, the console *and* a database I can query later. Using eg the [SQL Server sink](https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver) all you need to do to log to a database is add `.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(...)` with the database options in the configuration. The rest of the code doesn't even need to know there's a database involved. If you use filters, you can send errors to one file or table, info messages to another, critical messages to an email sink etc. You also get buffering out of the box, rolling files etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you give me a example project or video of that ? if it's there is a easyier way, i would like to learn that. EDİT: i just saw that you allready give to me a source to search it, thank you so much man. i will use that.

Comment: The [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) package integrates the Serilog library with ASP.NET Core's logging infrastructure. The SQL Server Sink is one more sink you can use with Serilog